# How to unzip ".zip" files?

Tags: command-line, games, unzip

**I downloaded some files from the web but I can't figure out how to access them...**

I'm going to have to go without Internet service for a week since other bills require my attention more. I was really bummed, Steam lacks a lot of free Linux games, but then I thought of Gamejolt! I went to the sight, found a few games and thought "*What the heck? I might as well give 'em a try for a week.*"

I download two games and both came in .zip files, the second being a ".zip.part" file-whatever that means.

I can't open them in *archive manager* and I can't run them as a *Wine application* either. I looked for an answer to unzip .zip files and I haven't found a helpful answer, nor a recent one. Some people said to install the unzip command, I attempt to do so and something goes wrong. I try the unzip command, thinking that maybe I already had it, and something goes wrong. How do I unzip these games? I have maybe a day left before it gets turned off and I'm growing concerned.

When I try to install unzip, I get this:

```
*E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)*

*E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?*
```

When I try to unzip the program, I get this:

```
*unzip:  cannot find or open renryuu-ascension-17.05.15-linux-version.zip.part, renryuu-ascension-17.05.15-linux-version.zip.part.zip or renryuu-ascension-17.05.15-linux-version.zip.part.ZIP.*
```

When I try to unzip the program without the ".part" piece, I get this:

```
*unzip:  cannot find or open renryuu-ascension-17.05.15-linux-version.zip, renryuu-ascension-17.05.15-linux-version.zip.zip or renryuu-ascension-17.05.15-linux-version.zip.ZIP.*
```

Please help me, the answer may be obvious but I really am new to the command line thing...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first issue on installing `unzip` is because of insufficient permissions. Chances are that you might have tried to install `unzip` with
`apt-get install unzip`. This is **not** enough.
You need to install `unzip` by:

> `sudo apt-get install unzip`

Chances are that `unzip` already exists in your system.
It would be the most common scenario. You can verify the install by the command

> `which unzip`

For your second issue, you are seeing a `.zip.part` extension because the the `zip` file was not completely downloaded. You can either try to download it again from the same source or choose a different source.

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to install anything - you can just use Python. This is from [zipfile — Work with ZIP archives — Python 3.7.2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html)

> ### Command-Line Interface
>
> The zipfile module provides a simple command-line interface to interact with ZIP archives.
>
> If you want to create a new ZIP archive, specify its name after the `-c` option and then list the filename(s) that should be included:
>
> ```
> $ python -m zipfile -c monty.zip spam.txt eggs.txt
> ```
>
> Passing a directory is also acceptable:
>
> ```
> $ python -m zipfile -c monty.zip life-of-brian_1979/
> ```
>
> If you want to extract a ZIP archive into the specified directory, use the `-e` option:
>
> ```
> $ python -m zipfile -e monty.zip target-dir/
> ```
>
> For a list of the files in a ZIP archive, use the `-l` option:
>
> ```
> $ python -m zipfile -l monty.zip
> ```
>
> ### Command-line options
>
> `-l <zipfile>`
>   `--list <zipfile>`
>      List files in a zipfile.
>
> `-c <zipfile> <source1> ... <sourceN>`
>   `--create <zipfile> <source1> ... <sourceN>`
>     Create zipfile from source files.
>
> `-e <zipfile> <output_dir>`
>   `--extract <zipfile> <output_dir>`
>     Extract zipfile into target directory.
>
> `-t <zipfile>`
>   `--test <zipfile>`
>     Test whether the zipfile is valid or not.

So your command would be

```
$ python -m zipfile -e renryuu-ascension-17.05.15-linux-version.zip
```

Try the `-t` option for testing as well.

However, in your specific case, `.part` means that the file didn't finish downloading or it is currently downloading.